# Trouble with C++ merging files

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to write a program that takes numbers from two files and outputs them to another file in ascending order. The program compiles without any errors and creates an output file as it should, but the file is empty. What am I doing wrong?

First file:

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

Second file:

```
2
4
6  
8
```

-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void merging(ifstream& instream, ifstream& instream2, ofstream& outstream);

int main()
{
  ifstream instream, instream2;
  ofstream outstream;

  instream.open("merge1");
  if (instream.fail())
    {
      cout << "Failed to open input file.\n";
      exit (1);
    }

  instream.open("merge2");
  if (instream2.fail())
    {
      cout << "Failed to open input file.\n";
      exit (1);
    }

  outstream.open("merge3");
  if (outstream.fail())
    {
      cout << "Failed to open output file.\n";
      exit (1);
    }

  merging( instream, instream2, outstream);

  instream.close();
  instream2.close();
  outstream.close();

  cout << "Finished merging files.\n";

  return 0;
}

void merging(ifstream& instream, ifstream& instream2, ofstream& outstream)
{
  int number1, number2;

  if (instream >> number1)


  if(instream)
    {
      if (instream2 >> number2)
    {

      while (instream && instream2)
        {
          if (number1 <= number2)
            {
          outstream << number1 << " ";
            }

          if (! (instream >> number1))
            {
            outstream << number2 << " ";

            }

        }

          else
        {
          outstream << number2 << " ";


          if (! (instream >> number1))
            {
              outstream << number1 << " ";

            }
          else 
        }
        }
    }
      else
    {
      outstream << number1 << " ";

    }
    }

  while (instream >> number1)
    {
      outstream << number1 << " ";

    }

  while (instream2 >> number2)
    {
      outstream << number2 << " ";

    }


}
```

Comment: The standard `sort` tool already has this functionality.

Comment: read from file 1 into [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) read from file 2 into same vector. Run vector through [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). Write vector to file 3.

Comment: Debuggers are excellent tools.  If you haven't learned to use one, this would be an excellent opportunity.  Execute each statement individually, *watching* values of variables.  I highly recommend using one before posting to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem here:

```
instream.open("merge1");
...
instream.open("merge2");
```

You opened `instream` twice. You probably meant to open `instream` and then `instream2`

Once the files are ready, simply read content to `std::vector` and sort it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

...
std::vector<int> vec;

int i;
while (instream1 >> i)
    vec.push_back(i);

while (instream2 >> i)
    vec.push_back(i);

//sort the values
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

//output
for (auto n : vec)
    outstream << n << "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you, you were right, I did mean to open instream2 after instream. After fixing that the output file did have numbers but a few were out of order. I looked for mistakes similar to the one you found and here I wrote :  if (! (instream >> number1)) {outstream << number1 << " "; }  instead of  if (! (instream >> number1)) { outstream << number2 << " "; }  Now it works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: You should try the `std::vector` method instead, because it doesn't depend on the order of numbers in the two files. Unless you have been instructed not to use vector.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use it on this problem, but I will make sure to use it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Barmak Shemirani has the correct answer.

One minor improvement would be to use `std:set<>`, which is already weakly ordered -- so it doesn't require a seperate sort step.

```
std::set<int> numbers;
int i;

while (instream >> i)
    numbers.insert(i);

while (instream2 >> i)
    numbers.insert(i);

for (auto n : numbers)
    outstream << n << "\n";
```

Comment: Note that `std::set` will ignore duplicate entries, this may not be user's intention. Also `std::sort` is a bit faster, the result is that the two methods have about the same performance.

Comment: That's absolutely correct. The original example did not have any duplicates and the author didn't specify what should happen in such cases. As I mentioned in my answer, yours is correct. I just thought this alternative was a clean solution -- easy to understand.

As for performance, I believe the cost for balanced red-black insertions in std::set is something like O( _n * log(n)_ ), worst-case. The append for a vector is more-or-less linear, but the extra std::sort step is also something like O( _n * log(n)_ ).